# SQL aggregate functions value multiplication

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate, multiplication

In a single query I would like to `COUNT` and `GROUP_CONCAT` on two different columns from two different tables.

The issue is the number returned by the `COUNT` is multiplied by the number of different item in `GROUP_CONCAT`, and in the `GROUP_CONCAT` result, each different item is multiplied by the number that the COUNT should be returning.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT e.id, GROUP_CONCAT(c.id SEPARATOR ',') AS category_ids, COUNT(a.id) AS numberAttenders, e.event_capacity
FROM events e
LEFT JOIN attendees a ON a.event_id=e.id,
categories c,
event_categories ec
WHERE  e.id=ec.event_id 
AND ec.category_id=c.id 
GROUP BY e.id
HAVING numberAttenders < e.event_capacity OR e.event_capacity=0
```

And here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6acb1/1) so this is more clear/testable.

The result look like something like this:

```
id 1
category_ids 1,2,1,2
numberAttenders 4
event_capacity 10
```

When I would like to have something like this:

```
id 1
category_ids 1,2
numberAttenders 2
event_capacity 10
```

I played a little with the `GROUP BY` but had no successful result yet.

Comment: While providing a working sample is very much appreciated I would strongly recommend to add your query (best effort) to the question itself.

Comment: I added the query, thank you for your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a cartesian product of attendees and categories for each event.  The best solution is to aggregate the tables *before* doing the join:

```
SELECT e.id, ec.category_ids, a.NumAttendees, e.event_capacity
FROM events e LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT a.event_id, COUNT(*) as NumAttendees
      FROM attendees a
      GROUP BY a.event_id
     ) a
     ON a.event_id = e.id LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT ec.event_id, GROUP_CONCAT(c.id SEPARATOR ',') as category_ids
      FROM event_categories ec JOIN
           categories c
           ON ec.category_id = c.id 
      GROUP BY ec.event_id
     ) ec
     ON  e.id=ec.event_id 
HAVING NumAttendees < e.event_capacity OR e.event_capacity = 0;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6acb1/3) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is doing what I want. I never thought about this solution before, so it's a nice lesson you taught me today.